# MySQL - Display null column from child table if all values are not distinct

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables, for example:

invoices

```
ID Name
1   A
2   B
3   C
4   D
5   E
```

transactions

```
ID  Invoice_ID User_ID
1       1        10
2       1        10
3       1        10
4       2        30
5       3        20
6       3        40
7       2        30
8       2        30
9       4        40
10      3        50
```

Now I want to make a select that will pull the invoices and the user_id from the related transactions, but of course if I do that I won't get all the ids, since they may be distinct but there will be only one column for that. What I want to do is that if there are distinct User_ids, I will display a pre-defined text in the column instead of the actual result.

```
select invoices.id, invoices.name, transactions.user_id(if there are distinct user_ids -> return null)

from invoices
left join transactions on invoices.id = transactions.invoice_id
```

and then this would be the result

```
ID Name User_ID
1   A    10
2   B    30
3   C    null
4   D    40
5   E    null
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following :

```
select 
   invoices.id, 
   invoices.name, 
   IF (
      (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) FROM transactions WHERE transactions.invoice_id = invoices.id) = 1, 
      (SELECT MAX(user_id) FROM transactions WHERE transactions.invoice_id = invoices.id), 
      null
   ) AS user_id
from invoices
```

Or, alternatively, you can use the [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function to output a comma-separated list of users for each invoice. It is not exactly what you asked, but maybe in fact it will be more useful :

```
select 
    invoices.id, 
    invoices.name, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT transactions.user_id SEPARATOR ',') AS user_ids
from invoices
left join transactions on invoices.id = transactions.invoice_id
group by invoices.id
```

Comment: In this case it is always showing null if there is more than one transaction related to the invoice. I want to show null only if there are different user_id's between those transactions. Is that possible?

Comment: I have updated the COUNT subquery so that it will count the DISTINCT user_id of the transactions of an invoice

Answer (score 2):

Try somethingh like:

```
select i.id, i.name, t.user_id
from invoices i left join
(
   select invoice_ID, User_ID
   from transactions
   group by invoice_ID
   having count(invoice_ID)=1
) t on i.id=t.invoice_id
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d2856/2)

Answer (score 2):

You could list all the transactions that have multiple user ids, like this:

```
select invoices.id, invoices.name, null

from invoices
left join transactions on invoices.id = transactions.invoice_id having count(distinct transactions.user_id) > 1
```

Also, I think this `CASE` might suit your needs here:

```
select invoices.id, invoices.name, 
   case when count(distinct transactions.user_id) > 1 then null else transactions.user_id end     
from invoices
left join transactions on invoices.id = transactions.invoice_id 
group by invoices.id
```

although, I'm not sure this is syntactically correct

Comment: in this case every time there is more than one transaction it will show null, right? What if I want to display "null" only if there are different ID's?

Comment: different ID's of what table? transactions? then do  the group by on another column and do the count on transactions.id

Comment: yes, between the transactions related to a certain invoice. Like in my example, transactions 1, 2 and 3 are all related to invoice 1 and all have the samer user_id, in this case it would show the user_id because they are all equal. Ok I will try that approach. Thanks!

Comment: The second answer is mostly correct; `count(transactions.user_id)` should be `count(DISTINCT transactions.user_id)`. `COUNT` without an enclosed `DISTINCT` counts all non-null values, even if those values are the same.

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys.